# Redhat 7 : Where to find LFTP 4.8.3

Tags: centos, rhel, lftp

I have Red Hat 7 on the server and `LFTP 4.4.8`.

I had to use a CentOS RPM to upgrade to LFTP `4.4.8`.

I need to upgrade to a more recent version because some option are not available in `LFTP 4.4.8`.

But I'm having a hard time finding more recent RPM.

I went there http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lftp but there is nothing for Red Hat 7 or CentOS after `LFTP 4.4.8`.

Do you have any idea? I start to think I will not be able to get something more recent than `LFTP 4.4.8` on Red Hat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes on [SUSE Build service](https://build.opensuse.org) you can get recent packages. [lftp-4.8.4](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:nikke:lftp/lftp)

Despite this build service is from SUSE team but it provides to build packages for couple of popular distributions.

---

Beware! This package is not official. This packages are built by people for their own needs with no warranty.

You can build your own `lftp` from source and install it (maybe create your own `rpm`) also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly I can't afford to use untrusted package. I''ll switch to rsync. Thanks again